# as3 why is my public var changing?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a var called "currentMystery" I have reduced the issue down to these two functions
I believe. Anyway, the first time through it works and traces a var from an Array... but the second time through something is changing it to [Event type="soundComplete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]

What in the code is changing this or what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks so much!

Any ideas on how to keep it as the same var as it assigned here:

```
currentMystery = "" + Mystries[4] + "";
```

...

```
public static var Mystries:Array = new Array("null","Joyful","Luminous","Sorrowful","Glorious");

    public function checkDecade(e:Event = null)
    {
        if (decadeCount < 6)
        {
            Announce = true;
            currentMystery = "" + Mystries[4] + "";
            prayDecade(currentMystery);

        }
    }


    public function prayDecade(currentMystery:String)
    {

  //// MY ISSUE IS WITH currentMystery. First time through 
  //// it works but the second through it is changing to 
  //// something like [Event type="soundComplete" bubbles=false etc...
  trace("Pray Decade called: " +currentMystery);


        if (Announce)
        {
            /// Sets PAUSE before Announc || Add features later to all prayers
            setTimeout(function()
               {
                    MainDoc.cPrayer.text = currentMystery;
                    trace("Called Announce"+decadeCount);
                    trace("Called Announce: Mystery: " + currentMystery+" Current Decade: " +decadeCount);
                    theAnnounce = new Sound();
                    theAnnounce.load(new URLRequest("audio/Rosary/Announce/"+currentMystery+"/"+decadeCount+".mp3"));
                    Praying = theAnnounce.play();
                    Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, prayDecade );
                    Announce = false;
                }, 2000);

        }
        else
        {
            if (prayerCount==0)
            {
                trace("Our Father " + decadeCount);
                //trace(love);
                Begin = true;
                /// Sets PAUSE before Our Father || Add features later to all prayers
                setTimeout(function()
                   {
                     Begin = true;
                     ourFather(); 
                   }, 2000);

            }

            if (prayerCount >0 && prayerCount<11)
            {
                trace("Hail Mary " + prayerCount);
                Begin = true;
                hailMary();
            }

            if (prayerCount==11)
            {
                trace("Glory Be... " + prayerCount);
                Begin = true;
                gloryBe();
            }
            if (prayerCount==12)
            {
                trace("Oh My Jesus... " + prayerCount);
                Begin = true;
                ohMyJesus();
            }
            function ourFather(e:Event = null)
            {
                if (Begin)
                {
                    Praying = OFB.play();
                    Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, ourFather );
                }
                else
                {


                    Praying = OFE.play();
                    Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, prayDecade );
                    prayerCount++;
                }
                Begin = false;
            }

            function hailMary(e:Event = null)
            {
                if (Begin)
                {
                    Praying = HMB.play();
                    Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, hailMary );
                }
                else
                {
                    Praying = HME.play();
                    Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, prayDecade );
                    prayerCount++;
                }
                Begin = false;
            }

            function gloryBe(e:Event = null)
            {
                if (Begin)
                {
                    Praying = GBB.play();
                    Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, gloryBe );
                }
                else
                {
                    Praying = GBE.play();
                    Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, checkDecade );
                    prayerCount++;
                }
                Begin = false;
            }

            function ohMyJesus(e:Event = null)
            {
                Praying = OMJ.play();
                Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, checkDecade );
                prayerCount = 0;
                decadeCount++;
            }

        }//End if Else
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `prayDecade` method as a handler for the sound complete event as well as calling it directly in your code. When it is invoked as an event handler, the parameter it receives is an event object which is being cast to a `string` and overwriting your public variable within the local (`prayDecade` function) scope.

I think if you update the function as follows you'll get the results you expect (assuming `currentMystery` is a public variable in the class scope:

```
public function prayDecade(e:Event)
{
    trace("Pray Decade called: " + currentMystery);

    // ....
}
```

And when you invoke the method directly, don't pass the variable:

```
// Assuming currentDecade is in scope in the prayDecade method
prayDecade(/*currentMystery*/);
```

Comment: This worked. :) How could I pass a var to it? I guess I don't need to.
I could just do this every time I change a var from the array. currentMystery = "" + Mystries[4] + ""; prayDecade(); I put a null in the function and it works, just wondering if there is a better way: public function prayDecade(e:Event = null)

Answer (score 1):

> What in the code is changing this or what am I doing wrong?

Event handler for the 'SoundChannel' is wrong.

```
Praying.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, prayDecade );
```

In the `prayDecade` as an argument will be passed [event object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html) ([Event.SOUND_COMPLETE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html#event%3asoundComplete)), not a string as you are waiting for. So `[Event type="soundComplete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]` is a String representation of event.